# django-REST: Nested relationships vs PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: django-rest-framework

Is it better to use nested relationships or PrimaryKeyRelated field if you have lots of data?

I have a model with deep relationships.
For simplicity I did not add the colums.

**Model:**

[image: Model]

**Usecase:**

1. User creates 1 Workoutplan with 2 Workouts and 3 WorkoutExercises.
2. User creates 6 Sets for each WorkoutExercise/Exercise.
3. User starts workout > new FinishedWorkout is created
4. User does first exercise and enters the used weights > new FinishedWorkoutExercise with FinishedSet is created

**Question:**

I want to track the progression for each workoutplan > workout > exercise.
So with time the user may have finished dozens of workouts therefore hundreds if sets are already in the database.

If I now use nested Relationships I may load a lot of data I don't need.
But if I use PrimaryKeyRelatedFields I have to load all the data I need separately which means more effort in my frontend.

Which method is preferred in such a situation?

**Edit:**
If I use PrimaryKeyRelatedFields how do I distinguish if e.g. Workouts in Workoutplan is an array with primary keys or an array with the loaded objects?

Comment: I thought code was not necessary, because changing NestedRel. to PrimaryKeyRelatedEntities is just a few lines of trivial code in the django-model. And the retrieval on the front-end is pretty much the same for both.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PrimaryKeyRelatedField, you'll have a big overload to request the the necessary data in frontend

In your case, I would create specific serializers with the fields you want (using `Meta.fields` attribute). So, you won't load unecessary data and the frontend won't need to request more data from backend.

I can write a sample code, if you need more details.

Comment: I agree. I have a snippet that let's you dynamically load serializers from an object so your viewset knows when to use, say, WorkoutCreateSerializer instead of WorkoutListSerializer. I'll upload that here when I get to my PC in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'll get to the question regarding serializers in a second, but first of all and for clarification. What is the purpose of having duplicate models as Workout/Finished Workout, Set/Finished Set,...?

Why not...

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    #...stuff...
    finished = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    #...more stuff...
```

Then you can just set a finished date on a workout when it's done.

Now, regarding the question. I would suggest you think about user interactions. What parts of the front-end are you trying to populate? How is the data related and how would the user access it?

You should think about what parameters you're querying DRF with. You can send a date and expect workouts finished on a specific day:

```
// This example is done in Angular, but you get the point...
var date= {
    'day':'24',
    'month':'10',
    'year':'2015'
};
API.finishedWorkout.query(date).$promise
.then(function(workouts){
    //...workouts is an array of workout objects...
});
```

Viewset...

```
class FinishedWorkoutViewset(viewsets.GenericAPIView,mixins.ListModelMixin):
    serializer_class = FinishedWorkOutSerializer
    queryset = Workout.objects.all()
    def list(self, request):
        user = self.request.user
        day = self.data['day'];
        month = self.data['month'];
        year = self.data['year'];
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset().filter(finished__date=datetime.date(year,month,day)).filter(user=user))
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return response.Response(serializer.data)
```

And then your **FinishedWorkoutSerializer** can just have whatever fields you want for that specific type of query.

This leaves you with a bunch of very specific URLs, which isn't all that great, but you can use specific serializers for those interactions and you're also open to dynamically changing the filter, depending on what paramaters are in `self.data`.

There is also a chance that you may want to filter differently depending what method is being called, say you want to list only active exercises, but if a user queries a specific exercise, you want him to have access to it (note that the Exercise object should have a `models.BooleanField` attribute called "active").

```
class ExerciseViewset(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    serializer_class = ExerciseSerializer
    queryset = Exercise.objects.all()
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset().filter(active=True))
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return response.Response(serializer.data)
```

Now you have different objects show up on the same URL, depending on the action. It's a bit closer to what you need, but you're still using the same serializer, so if you need a huge nested object on `retrieve()`, you're also gonna get a bunch of them when you `list()`.

In order to keep lists short and details nested, you need to use different serializers.

Let's say you want to only send exercises' `pk` and `name` attributes when they are listed, but whenever an exercise is queried, you wan't to send along all related "Set" objects ordered inside an array of "WorkoutSets"...

```
# Taken from an SO answer on an old question...
class MultiSerializerViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializers = { 
        'default': None,
    }
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializers.get(self.action, self.serializers['default'])


class ExerciseViewset(MultiSerializerViewSet, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    queryset = Exercise.objects.all()
    serializers = {
        'default': SimpleExerciseSerializer,
        'retrieve': DetailedExerciseSerializer
    }
```

Then your serializers.py could look a bit like...

```
#------------------Exercise
#--------------------------Simple List
class SimpleExerciseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model Exercise
        fields = ('pk','name')

#--------------------------Detailed Retrieve
class ExerciseWorkoutExerciseSetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model Set
        fields = ('pk','name','description')

class ExerciseWorkoutExerciseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    set_set = ExerciseWorkoutExerciseSetSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model WorkoutExercise
        fields = ('pk','set_set')

class DetailedExerciseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    workoutExercise_set = exerciseWorkoutExerciseSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model Exercise
        fields = ('pk','name','workoutExercise_set')
```

I'm just throwing around use cases and attributes that probably make no sense in your model, but I hope this is helpfull.

P.S.; Check out how Java I got in the end there :p "ExcerciseServiceExcersiceBeanWorkoutFactoryFactoryFactory"